# Div is not displayed on screen, am I missing some CSS properties?

Tags: html, css

I have built this personal web page and for some reason, the last part of the page (a table container) is not displayed on the screen.

```css
* {
  padding: 0%;
  margin: 0%;
}

body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}

/* more CSS properties goes here (not relevant for this question)*/
#fotter {
  height: 30%;
  background-image: url(bottom.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  opacity: 0.6;
  display: flex;
}

#fotter-title {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 22%;
  left: 45%;
  font-size: 250%;
}

#table-div {
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
}

#row-div {
  display: table-row;
  height: 100%;
}

.image-title {
  display: table-cell;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 30%;
  height: 30%;
}

#first {
  background: url(first.jpg);
  width: 100%;
}

#second {
  background: url(second.jpg);
  height: 100%;
}

#third {
  background: url(third.jpg.);
}

#forth {
  background: url(forth.jpg);
}
```

```html
<div id="heading"></div>
<h1 id="heading-title">Hi, my name is Imanuel Sinwany</h1>
<div id="body-div">
  <div id="left-div">
    <div id="body-text">
      <p>...............</p>
      <p>...............</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="right-div"></div>
</div>
<div id="fotter">
  <div id="table-div">
    <div id="row-div">
      <div id="first" class="image-div">
      </div>
      <div id="second" class="image-div">
      </div>
      <div id="third" class="image-div">
      </div>
      <div id="forth" class="image-div">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<h1 id="fotter-title">My Gallery</h1>
```

I have tried to include the relevant code.

My question is why I can't see the last table (inside "footer" div id) Am I missing some properties?

Thanks for the helpers!

Comment: The divs have no content. What are you expecting to see?

Comment: Hi, The background - I have some personal images which I expect to see

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `#table-div` element needs a defined width. Otherwise it will collapse to zero pixels because there is no content within the child elements.

The bottom level divs should also use `display: table-cell`.

```css
* {
  padding: 0%;
  margin: 0%;
}

body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}

#fotter {
  height: 30%;
  background-image: url(bottom.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  opacity: 0.6;
  display: flex;
}
#table-div {
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#row-div {
  display: table-row;
  height: 100%;
}

#row-div > div {
  display: table-cell;
  outline: 1px solid orange;
}

#first {
  background: url(https://placehold.it/100x100?text=FIRST);
}

#second {
  background: url(https://placehold.it/100x100?text=SECOND);
}

#third {
  background: url(https://placehold.it/100x100?text=THIRD);
}

#forth {
  background: url(https://placehold.it/100x100?text=FORTH);
}
```

```html
<div id="fotter">
  <div id="table-div">
    <div id="row-div">
      <div id="first" class="image-div">
      </div>
      <div id="second" class="image-div"> 
      </div>
      <div id="third" class="image-div">
      </div>
      <div id="forth" class="image-div">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about putting `<table>` instead of `<div>`?

```
<div id="heading"></div>
 <h1 id="heading-title">Hi, my name is Imanuel Sinwany</h1>
  <div id="body-div">
   <div id="left-div">
    <div id="body-text">
     <p>...............</p>
     <p>...............</p>
    </div>
   </div>
  <div id="right-div"></div>
</div>
 <div id="fotter">
  <table id="table-div">
   <tr id="row-div">
    <td id="first" class="image-div"></td>
    <td id="second" class="image-div"></td>
    <td id="third" class="image-div"></td>
    <td id="forth" class="image-div"></tr>
   </tr>
  </table>
  </div>
 <h1 id="fotter-title">My Gallery</h1>
```

And CSS:

```
* {
padding: 0%;
margin: 0%;
 }

body, html {
 height: 100%;
 }

 /* more CSS properties goes here (not relevant for this question)*/
#fotter {
  height: 30%;
  background-image: url(bottom.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  opacity: 0.6;
  display: flex;
  }

 #fotter-title {
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 22%;
   left: 45%;
   font-size: 250%;
   }

 table {
   border: 1px solid red;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   }

 #row-div {
   height: 100%;
  }

 #first {
   background: url(https://placehold.it/100x100?text=FIRST);
  }

  #second {
   background: url(https://placehold.it/100x100?text=SECOND);
   }

  #third {
    background: url(https://placehold.it/100x100?text=THIRD);
  } 

  #forth {
   background: url(https://placehold.it/100x100?text=FORTH);
   }
```

Comment: I used @Turnip background images as same samples.

Comment: Hi, 'table' is gonna work, but as I understand 'div' is more in use and I want to practice this form.

Comment: So maybe you want to try grid?